Windows log alert, message field extraction
I have built a windows log collection and alarm system of "promtail+loki+alertmanager".
How can I get the value of the first 30 characters of "message" in the windows system log in the alarm rule of loki? Otherwise, it is not clear in the alarm what caused the alarm. Thank you
loki related configuration is as follows
groups:
    - name: windows_test_alerts
      rules:
        - alert: testServiceStopped
          expr: |
              count_over_time( {ip="10.203.11.13"} |= `message` [1m]) > 0
          for: 0m
          labels:
            severity: info
            source: loki
          annotations:
            description: {{ $?.message }}, {{ $labels.ip }} .

promtail related configuration is as follows
scrape_configs:
- job_name: windows
  windows_events:
    eventlog_name: "Application"
    use_incoming_timestamp: true
    xpath_query: '*'
    bookmark_path: "./bookmark-application.xml"
    exclude_event_data: true
    exclude_user_data: true
    labels:
      systemlog: windowslog 
      logsource: windows-Applicationlog 
      ip: 10.203.11.13   
      Remarks: "F15-5 win test machine"  
  pipeline_stages:
  - json:
      expressions:
        source: source
        eventID: event_id
        level: levelText
        message: Message
  - labels:
        source: $source
        eventID: $eventID
        level: $level

How can I correctly extract the message information and display it in the alarm?
